# Algolia save only strings using Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, algolia

I use Laravel 5.4 and i integrate algolia with my project, but I have some problems with data type of columns.

If I run the command from the localhost, status columns (and others) appear like integer in algolia database, but if I run the same artisan command from the production environment, the status column is now string, and I can't use                `->where('status', 1)` in my code, because algolia can use only integers for where clauses.

Is there a problem with my database? But is the same database from my localhost, same mysql version...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what could be the reason of this, but I think I know a good work around.

Let me also say that Algolia can have string as a where clause, but it's an intentional limitation of Laravel Scout.

You can use the toSearchableArray in your model to customize the array sent to Algolia. I'd use it to cast the data.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scout#configuring-searchable-data

You should have something like this:

```
public function toSearchableArray()
{
    $data = $this->toArray();

    $data['attribute'] = (int) $data['attribute'];

    return $data;
}
```